# Why are these the number of operations for each line in this pseudocode?

Tags: data-structures, pseudocode

I am watching a lecture on data structures from my course and I don't really understand the part where the lecturer translates each line into operations.
Can someone please explain how they are obtaining  2n +1, 2(n-1), 2(n-1), 2(n-1), 1 and finally 8n-2. I have tried my best to understand it but I can't.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The counter denotes the number of operations (e.g. addition, subtraction, multiplication, accessing index etc.). In simple terms, each of these operations can be done in a single (or smallest) unit of time. For example:

```
currentMax <- A[0]
```

There are two operations, one accessing the zeroth index. Second, assigning it to the variable currentMax.

Similarly in the loop, if you are doing one operation in each iteration, you will end up doing total "n" operations where n is the length of the array.

```
for i <- 1 to n-1 do
```

Let's walk through this line, for the first iteration you are assigning value 1 to i, that will be 1 operation. In each iteration, you will subtract 1 from n (for evaluating n-1) and you also need to compare i with n-1 which will be another operation. So, for n iterations, you will perform n * 2. That's how you get 2n+1 for this statement in pseudocode.

Comment: Apologies, I am still confused, how does this answer my questions I had? How is the lecturer getting those specific numbers for each line? (2n+1, 2(n-1) etc)

Comment: @futuredeveloper, Added one example, let me know if you want any explanation further.

Comment: for the example you did: for i <- 1 to n-1 do, surely this should just be n-1 operations? since lets say n is 10, i = 1, so number of times this loop will run will be 9 times hence n-1?

Comment: @futuredeveloper, Good catch, Total counter for this step should be 2n-1 instead of 2n+1.

Comment: why 2n-1 and not n-1?, where is the 2 coming from? @Devesh

Comment: There are two operations in "for i <- 1 to n-1 do". First subtraction to evaluate n-1, second, comparison "i<n-1". These two operations are repeated n-1 times. So the total will be 2(n-1). And, you have done one assignment "i=1" for the very first time only. Hence grand total for this step becomes 2(n-1) + 1 = 2n-1.

Comment: what i don't understand is for this for loop: for(i=0; i<=2*n; i++), this runs 2n + 1 times simple since it runs from 0 to 2n, so 2n + 1. But the approach you took for for i <- 1 to n-1 do, is different from the approach they took there. @Devesh

Comment: @futuredeveloper, Explain to me what is your understanding in detail and I can fill the gaps for you. I'm giving you a totally unrelated example just for the sake of uderstanding. How many primitive operations does it take to do a comparison? Only 1 but Say you have two numbers and a and b, and you want to check if a is at least 5 units less than b, You will use "a < b - 5", How many primitive operations are you doing for this comparison? The correct answer is 2. How? Well, one is subtraction and another is comparison. Now, ponder are you doing something similar in the loop?